# python selenium checkbox nested label and input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get a checkmark on "**Minutes (1993-Present)**" from the federal reserve's document filter page with selenium.

https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/materials/

This is my code. I have tried the following ways, I keep get "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: Unable to locate element"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/materials/")

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="article"]/app-root/div/ng-component/div[1]/div/div/form/app-doc-types/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/label/input').click()
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group']/div/div[7]/label/input[contains(text(), 'Minutes (1993-Present)')]").click()
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.form-group div:nth-child(7) label input').click()
```

I sliced some parts of the HTML below.

```
<app-doc-types><div class="eventSearch__label">
  <p class="form-control-static">
    <strong><legend class="ng-binding">Type:</legend></strong>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="eventSearch__inputs">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Agendas
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Beige Books/Redbooks
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Bluebooks
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Chairman's FOMC Press Conferences
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Greenbooks
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          Memos
        </label>
      </div><div class="col-lg-6">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
          Minutes (1993-Present)
        </label>
      </div><!---->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</app-doc-types>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some time for website to load. I added `time.sleep(2)` after opening the webpage with `driver`. 
Your first XPath should work, however it's extremely dependent on the structure of the page, therefore it may not work due to a little modification in the HTML structure of the page. 
Second XPath won't work, and actually you do not need to add `text()` check to the end of your path. This should work: 
`//div[@class='form-group']/div/div[7]/label/input`

 CSS Selector path should work, however your css path can be easily simplified. Check my solution below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/materials/")
time.sleep(2)
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.col-lg-6:nth-of-type(7) input').click()
```

Alternatively, you can use an `explicit wait`.

```py
driver.get("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/materials/")
element = WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.col-lg-6:nth-of-type(7) input')))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use playwright

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium # or "firefox" or "webkit".
    browser = await chromium.launch()
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/materials/")
    await page.click('xpath=/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/app-root/div/ng-component/div[1]/div/div/form/app-doc-types/div[2]/div/div/div[7]/label/input')
    await browser.close()
    
async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)
asyncio.run(main())
```